# Segmented button value to setPressed not working

Tags: sencha-touch-2, uisegmentedcontrol

I am creating a segmented button and i need to modify the app based on the value of the segmented button.

```
{

                    margin : '5 -5 0 25',
                    xtype: 'segmentedbutton',
                    allowMultiple: true,
                    height : 40,
                    id : 'fontStyleBtn',
                    items: [
                            {
                                text: 'B',
                                width : 50,
                                style: 'background-color:red !important',
                                action : 'boldText'
                            },
                        {
                            text: 'I',
                            width : 50,
                            style: 'font-size:14px;font-style:italic;background-color:#008c99',
                            action : 'italicText'
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'U',
                            width : 50,
                            style: 'font-size:14px;background-color:#008c99;text-decoration:underline',
                            action : 'underlineText'
                        }
                    ]}
```

when i tap on B, the text in my app is getting bold. But i need to set a value to it, so that next time i tap on it, i can reset the text to normal.

```
Ext.getCmp('fontStyleBtn').getItems()[0].pressed = true;
```

This doesn't seem to be working for me.

Answer (score 0):

Does `Ext.getCmp('fontStyleBtn').getItems()[0]` exactly return the "B" button?

If yes, try this instead:

`Ext.getCmp('fontStyleBtn').getItems()[0].setPressed(true);`

Comment: I put the values in an array and used setPressedButtons() method to set the value. Worked fine for me.